# Confusing moderator's comment on deleted answer

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

I posted accidentally [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28267514/segmentation-fault-in-x86-example-program/28268086#28268086) on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28267791/segmentation-fault-and-hang-in-assembly-code/28268029). When I noticed the mistake I deleted the posting. An hour later I could answer the question and edited the deleted posting and undeleted it. But the wrong answer appeared in the edit-history, to my dislike. So I deleted the answer again and added the right answer as new answer.

Now I get a comment of a moderator on the **deleted** answer:

> If you think you've found a duplicate question please vote to close
>   rather than posting duplicate answers. –  ChrisF

Where did I go wrong? I didn't think that I found a duplicate **question** and I didn't post duplicate answers and I don't want to vote to close the question.

Comment: Very often, answers from the same user that contain the same text (or mostly the same text) are answers posted on duplicate questions. If the moderator came across your answers through an interface that does not provide the full context, they might have looked like answers on *different*, duplicate questions, even though this is not the case here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You 'copy/pasted' a previous answer to the other question. I guess that triggered a moderator flag to check on your post. The moderator left you a message indicating the same answer on another question should be handled appropriately, by flagging or voting to close a a duplicate.

If this all happened by accident, there is no problem.

Comment: Thx, now I understand: The issue is not the two identical answers on the one question but the copypasted answer on the other question. But the first question was already deleted when I copypasted the text...